# Only some Discs [Kubuntu]

Tags: kubuntu, dvd, filemanager, cd, blu-ray

My blu-ray discs appear empty in the file manager, and they don't have the proper title? Some regular CD and Dvds have the same issue.

Why won't the contents display?

Thanks, I appreciate your time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get some Blu-ray movies to work by downloading VLC media player

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc`

then

`sudo apt-get install vlc libaacs0 libbluray-bdj libbluray1`

`mkdir -p ~/.config/aacs/`

`cd ~/.config/aacs/ && wget http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/files/KEYDB.cfg`

then

`vlc` which should open a VLC media player window

Go to the tab that says: Media > Open Disc

Make "Disc Selection" Blu-ray, click "Browse..." and select the movie under the media tab, and under the current session holder's name, you should see the name of the movie, select that and click "OK" and then "Play"! Then it should play!